# How to create an interactive UI in android wherein the number of UI depends on the loop and put it in a scrollview

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Sample UI:

[image: Img1]

In the sample UI, basic and premium are products wherein it is requested in an API. In my current code, I've designed it in my xml file only and it is not interactive. What I want to know is when the request has only one product, it will show 1 box only and if 2, 2 boxes and so on. I want to know if there's a possible way to do it not in the xml file and it should be in a scrollview. Please help me. Thanks. :)

Output should be like this:

[image: Img2]

current xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mojo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mavshack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="1dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeMain"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/mavshack_login" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
            android:id="@+id/chooseplan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_top_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/select_plan"
            android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_alrt_ttl" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chooseplan"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/got_activation_code_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/got_activation_code_margin" >

            <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
                android:id="@+id/basic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/plan_basic"
                android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_alrt_ttl" />

            <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
                android:id="@+id/premium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/plan_premium"
                android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_alrt_ttl" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/asd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/basic"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/basicRectangle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/basic"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp" >

                    <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/plan_HD"
                        android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_alrt_title"
                        mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_alrt_ttl" />

                    <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/plan_3Device"
                        android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_db_txt"
                        mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_db_menu" />

                    <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/plan_basicPrice"
                        android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_db_txt"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_db_menu" />

                    <com.mavshack.views.MavshackButton
                        android:id="@+id/basicbutton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                        android:text="@string/plan_choose"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_db_settings_paneltxt"
                        mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_button_txt" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/premiumRectangle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/premium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp" >

                    <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/plan_UHD"
                        android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_alrt_title"
                        mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_alrt_ttl" />

                    <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/plan_UDevice"
                        android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_db_txt"
                        mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_db_menu" />

                    <com.mavshack.views.MavshackTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/plan_premiumPrice"
                        android:textColor="@color/mavshack_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_db_txt"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_db_menu" />

                    <com.mavshack.views.MavshackButton
                        android:id="@+id/premiumbutton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                        android:text="@string/plan_choose"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fs_db_settings_paneltxt"
                        mojo:font_type="@integer/fnt_button_txt" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes ,make a layout inside the scroll-view and inflate child make separate 
xml file which you want to inflate.and inflate from your java code

http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/03/inflating-ui-dynammically-example-in.html